# My array returns array inside foreach

Tags: php

could someone explain me why I can not get the data from that array?
My echo only returns  "array". where I'm going wrong?

```
<?php
$people = array( 
array("name"=>"Bob","age"=>8,"colour"=>"red"), 
array("name"=>"Greg","age"=>12,"colour"=>"blue"), 
array("name"=>"Andy","age"=>5,"colour"=>"purple")); 


foreach($people as $vperson => $person){ 

    echo $person;

} 
?>
```

Comment: Because your array is a ___nested___ array; each element of the $people array, is a sub-array

Comment: If you are looking to print the names ... Do this `echo $person['name'];` instead of `echo $person;`

Comment: use print_r instead of echo .. $vperson will print the key and $person will print the nested array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as you said you have an array, your variable $person is also an array so you can't just make echo on that. You can access values by the names "age, name and colour".

Try this:

```
<?php
$people = array( 
array("name"=>"Bob","age"=>8,"colour"=>"red"), 
array("name"=>"Greg","age"=>12,"colour"=>"blue"), 
array("name"=>"Andy","age"=>5,"colour"=>"purple")); 


foreach($people as $vperson => $person){ 

    echo $name = $person['name'];
    echo $age = $person['age'];
    echo $colour = $person['colour'];
    echo "<br>";

} 
?>
```

Comment: Also you can do a var_dump inside your foreach, like this: var_dump($person) then you will get better how it works.

Comment: many thanks friend to fix my problem and give me the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Because, your are printing array with `echo`.

You can print the array like:

```
    <?php
    $people = array( 
    array("name"=>"Bob","age"=>8,"colour"=>"red"), 
    array("name"=>"Greg","age"=>12,"colour"=>"blue"), 
    array("name"=>"Andy","age"=>5,"colour"=>"purple")); 
    foreach($people as $vperson => $person){ 
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($person);
    echo '</pre>';


echo $name = $person['name'];
    echo $age = $person['age'];
    echo $colour = $person['colour'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to display key and equivalent value

```
foreach($people as $pe)
{
  foreach($pe as $key => $person) 
  {
     echo $key.' : '.$person.' </br> ';
  }
}
```